# Warning message saying the '.credentials' folder can't be found and Safari won't load 'localhost'

Tags: python, google-drive-api, localhost, compiler-warnings

I am trying out the Google Drive API (in Python) for a project of mine.
I have setup an API, and am using the [Python Quickstart API Code](https://github.com/samlopezf/google-drive-api-tutorial/blob/master/google-drive-api-tutorial-project/quickstart.py) (No modifications at all).

When I try and run the code, I get a warning message in the Python console saying

> UserWarning: Cannot access `/Users/everyone/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json`: No such file or directory

I had a feeling that it was because on OSX (and maybe other operating systems) a folder name starting with a dot will hide it to a normal user, so that made it so Python couldn't access it.

In the script (line 35 on the GitHub link: `os.makedirs(credential_dir)` and `credential_dir` - line 33 - `credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')`) I changed `.credentials` to `credentials` so it was not a hidden folder.

It still gave me a message saying the folder could not be found. How can I get it to find the folder?

This is the first problem and since it is only a warning, it continues the script.

The next problem is that, once the browser opens and you sign in, it should redirect you to the 'localhost' page to return the files in your Drive or something (I don't actually know as I don't get that far!), which it does, but I get:

> Safari can't open this page. Safari can't open - `http://localhost:8080/?code=4/wgDGzg5zJbYa0sWhve5zQK7Z0inog_QuD036wrfW0qXa_AByllGYWvBaw-INdEHp6Jj33heYxIrblto6kByA9WU&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly - becuase the server unexepectedly dropped the connection. ...`

This is annoying becuase it doesn't let the API return the files in my drive.

Is there a fix to this?

Thanks in advance,
Dream.

Comment: Dotfiles being hidden from things in unix only applies to directory lists from ls , not opening files of a given name.   There's no other distinction.   That's not your problem.

Comment: The OSX interface may hide dot files from you, the user, but that's just the interface. python can see it just fine - as long as it exists. Does it? The python script you generate should create it, BUT it should create it in /Users/<your user name>/.credentials, I'm not sure why your error references user e`everyone` instead.

Comment: try this: `ls ~/.credentials` - does the folder exist? Anything in it?

Comment: For everyone asking does the folder exist, yes it does. Doing 'sudo ls' and looking at the dotfiles I can see '.credentials'. There is nothing it the folder (ls ~/.credentials returns nothing). ~Thanks so far, Dream

Comment: Well, if there is nothing in folder, the error message you post is expected. The fact that you can't see a folder starting with a dot in some or all directory listing software, is merely a feature of such software, you should check the folder/file permissions for permissions. But if the file you're opening isn't there, you should expect a file not found.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues How shall I get that file? I googled it and looked on the official API page and there is no download / doesn't metion anything about a `drive-python-quickstart.json` file.

Comment: Update - Using TextEdit, I created a JSON file with that name and moved it to that directory - I am no longer getting that warning. Now I have to fix the Safari error. Dream

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

To remove the warning message I just simply created a JSON file with that name, using TextEdit, and moved it to the `.credentials` folder.

To resolve `localhost` error on Safari (and other browsers - Chrome didn't work):

> Using `Shift + Command + G` on the desktop, navigate to `/ect/hosts/`.
>   Open up Terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/hosts`.
>   Using arrow keys to go to the line, delete `::1     localhost`.
>   Press `Control + O`.
>   Hit `Enter`.
>   Then press `Control + X` to exit.
>   Open up the `hosts` file to check that line has been deleted.
>   If it has, when rerunning the script, after signing in and giving it permisions, you should no longer see a `Can't connect` error.

This is a good website on how to do it: [How to edit '/ect/hosts/' - Mac](https://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want)

How I got to the fix (Snark's post): [Unbale to reach 'localhost'](https://superuser.com/questions/30827/safari-is-unable-to-reach-localhost-127-0-0-1)

Dream